# Modifying plainurl bst file to add other preprint servers

Tags: bibtex, urls, urlbst

I'm rather new to this and I'm trying to modify the standard plainurl bst file to add other links on top of the usual ones (arxiv/doi/pubmed/url).

By mimicking exactly what appears in the file I'm able to do so, but the preprint server I'd like to resolve needs a final '/' on the url otherwise the page appears to be non-existent.

Specifically, other than the pieces I had to define in ENTRY, STRINGS etc. needed, I have

```
FUNCTION {format.newserver}
{ newserver empty$
    { "" }
    { newserverprefix number * newserverurl number * make.href }
  if$
}
```

which in the bibliography prints me newserverprefix:number hyperreff'ed to http://newserverurl/number.

I would like to be it hyperreff'ed to "http://newserverurl/number/". How can I achieve it?

Comment: Welcome! Since you didn't add a compilable example it's hard to test anything. However try adding `"/" *` after `make.href`...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was indeed able to fix it doing exactly like you suggested - I just had problems with how the * works. Now I wrapped my head around!

Comment: My previous suggestion was not correct. I wrote an answer with a better suggestion and an explantion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a proper example to test it is hard to say anything for sure, but if all you want to do is to add a trailing `/`, then you can use `"/" *` after `newserverprefix number *` to add to the printed text and/or after `newserverurl number *` to add to the actual URL:

```
FUNCTION {format.newserver}
{ newserver empty$
    { "" }
    { newserverprefix number * "/" * % This adds / to the printed text
         newserverurl number * "/" * % This adds / to the actual URL
      make.href }
  if$
}
```

---

#### An explanation:

The BibTeX language usees Reverse Polish Notation (RPN), or Postfix Notation, which means that you add items to a stack, and then use operators to do something on that stack.

The `format.newserver` function adds `newserver` to the stack and then uses the  `empty$` function. This function will test if the topmost item of the stack is empty (what a surprise!) and will leave the result on the top of the stack.

The function then adds two more items to the stack: `""` and `newserverprefix number * newserverurl number * make.href`, and then uses the `if$` function. This function will take three items from the top of the stack and checks if the third (top-down) is true. If so, the second item is put back on the stack, otherwise the first.

In case the `newserver` is empty, the function returns `""`, so we know that the entire function should only return a string. In case `newserver` isn't empty, then `newserverprefix number * newserverurl number * make.href` is used.

That sequence puts `newserverprefix` and `number` on the stack and concatenates both strings with `*`. It then puts `newserverurl` and  `number` on the stack and concatenates these with `*`. Then `make` takes the topmost two items on the stack and writes the URL. The second item (top-down) is the text to be printed, and the first item is the actual URL.

So to add a trailing `/` you need to add another item to the stack, the string `"/"`, and concatenate it with the URL text and/or the URL with a `*`:

```
newserverprefix % add newserverprefix 
number          % add number
*               % concatenate
"/"             % add "/"
*               % concatenate
newserverurl    % add newserverurl
number          % add number
*               % concatenate
"/"             % add "/"
*               % concatenate
make.href       % make the hyper-reference
```